# using the DOM to output different sized pyramids to a webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css

Continuing from above, whenever the button is clicked, the pyramid of whatever height the user input into the text box does print. But, if you click the button again, it prints a whole new pyramid without removing the old one. What I need to know is how to add a line of code to the beginning of the drawPyramid Function that clears the old content before creating a new Pyramid in Vanilla Javascript, HTML, and/or CSS. I do have a lot of notes written for the code but that's mostly for me because it's just the way that I learn best is to overexplain everything that's happening in the code which I also would appreciate in responses if possible.

Here is the JavaScript portion of what I have:

```js
function determineHeightAndThenDrawPyramid() {
  //Sets height == to input value typed by user
  let height = document.getElementById("height").value;

  //Creates btn that 'onclick' calls the printPyramid function
  let btn = document.getElementById("MyBtn").addEventListener("click", printPyramid(height));
}

//Building the pyramid
function printPyramid(height) {
  //Figure out how to clear the old output??
  console.clear();

  let numBricks = 0;
  let numSpaces = 0;

  for (let row = 0; row < height; row++) {
    let layer = "";

    //figure out number of bricks and spaces
    numBricks = row + 2;
    numSpaces = height - row - 1;

    for (let i = 0; i < numSpaces; i++) {
      layer += ".";
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < numBricks; i++) {
      layer += "#";
    }
    //Prints layer to console

    console.log(layer);

    //Prints layer to DOM

    //Creates new paragraph element
    let para = document.createElement("p");
    //Creates a text node from layer variable
    let rowStr = document.createTextNode(layer);
    //Para becomes parent of rowStr
    para.appendChild(rowStr);
    //Grabs pyramid ID from HTML
    let element = document.getElementById("pyramid");
    //Element becomes parent of para
    element.appendChild(para);

    //Summation: 
    //element/para/rowStr. 
    //Element == ID of pyramid. 
    //Para(New paragraph tag) == rowStr.
    //rowStr == layer variable == string to build pyramid
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="height" />
<button id="MyBtn">Go!</button>
<div id="pyramid">--</div>
```

Thank you for any advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some important errors:

- When you set the event listener, you need to use a *function callback*, not a *called function*
- Use `append` instead of `appendChild`
- You need to get the height just after clicking the button
- Then, to remove the previous pyramid before appending the new one, just remove the contents of its container.
- Finally (or, better said, initially), the function assigning the event listener needs to be called only once.
- Advice: use `const` instead of `let` whenever possible.

The code snippet works.

```js
function assignListener() {
  //Sets height to the input DOM element
  const height = document.getElementById("height");

  // Save the button DOM element into btn,
  // not the result from addEventListener
  const btn = document.getElementById("MyBtn");

  // Use a lambda callback which will call printPyramid
  // with the current value (when user clicks) of the input `height`
  btn.addEventListener("click", () => printPyramid(height.value));
}

//Building the pyramid
function printPyramid(height) {
  //Figure out how to clear the old output??
  console.clear();

  let numBricks = 0;
  let numSpaces = 0;
  
  // ==> Find and empty pyramid before starting
  //Grabs pyramid ID from HTML
  const element = document.getElementById("pyramid");

  // ==> Empty `element` contents
  element.innerHTML = '';

  for (let row = 0; row < height; row++) {
    let layer = "";

    //figure out number of bricks and spaces
    numBricks = row + 2;
    numSpaces = height - row - 1;

    for (let i = 0; i < numSpaces; i++) {
      layer += ".";
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < numBricks; i++) {
      layer += "#";
    }
    //Prints layer to console

    console.log(layer);

    //Prints layer to DOM

    //Creates new paragraph element
    const para = document.createElement("p");

    // Creates a text node from layer variable
    const rowStr = document.createTextNode(layer);

    // Para becomes parent of rowStr
    // ==> Use `append` instead of `appendChild`
    para.append(rowStr);

    // Element becomes parent only of para
    // ==> Use `append` instead of `appendChild`
    element.append(para);

    //Summation: 
    //element/para/rowStr. 
    //Element == ID of pyramid. 
    //Para(New paragraph tag) == rowStr.
    //rowStr == layer variable == string to build pyramid
  }
}

// ==> Call the event listener assigner only once
assignListener();
```

```html
<input id="height" />
<button id="MyBtn">Go!</button>
<div id="pyramid">--</div>
```

Comment: Fixed more bugs. Some more advices.

Comment: A couple of questions, First, I forked my repl.it and used this code but it does the exact same thing my original code does for the first part and when I added the second code block I tried it three different areas. Two of them made it so that the pyramid didn't print at all and the last location threw an error because I've already declared element. Question 1: Why use lambda instead of what I had because that part already worked?  Question 2: When I use the second code block it stops the pyramid from printing at all so I'm not sure what to do with that?

Comment: Fixed the code to make it do what is asked for: find and empty the container before beginning.

Comment: `Why use lambda instead of what I had because that part already worked?` I don't know how you made it work, but the only way to make `addEventListener` to work is passing a *function callback*, not a *called function*.

Comment: I'm not sure what the difference between function callback and a called function are. I'll look them up soon. On my repli.it page I implemented your solution emptying the element string and it does exactly what I need so thank you for that! I did keep the first few lines as I had them though because it works and I'm going to ask my teacher about what you said and see if he can tell me why it does work. I'm still really new to programming so I don't know why it works when you say it shouldn't but I can follow up with you about my teacher's explanation if you'd like? Thanks again for the help!

Comment: So my teacher answered me. I had in my HTML code "onclick=determineHeightAndThenDrawPyramid". So that's why it seemed like it was working even though it would have returned undefined if I didn't have the onclick.on my button. I wrote it not really knowing what it did lol or that it was doing a command that I was trying to write using the DOM.

Comment: `what the difference between function callback and a called function` A function callback is a function definition. In your example, you effectively call (execute it) the function and use its return value as the 2nd parameter of `addEventListener`. In my example, I tell `addEventListener` to execute the function when the event occurs (not when I assign the event listener).

I hope this helps you better understand it.

Comment: `I had in my HTML code "onclick=determineHeightAndThenDrawPyramid".` I suggest to clearly split HTML code from JS code: don't use the old JS way. Instead, do as I did in the example code snippet (from JS, find the DOM element and then manipulate it).

As a comment for future questions, do your best to add in the question a fully working example. Here, I had to add (guessing) what you had in your HTML code.